# I want pass xml data to my requested rest api

Tags: xml

I want to pass all my xml tag data to my rest api, I created xml and sent in postman it returns empty array, when i sent json data it response return data. please help me any one, thank you.

Comment: my api url: https://aaohostels.com/api/two

Comment: my xml data: <?xml version="1.0"?>

<kronos_WFC version="1.0">
 <Request
 Object="System" 
 Action="Login"
 Username="{{ Ganesh }}"
 Password="{{ 123456 }}">
  
 </Request>
</kronos_WFC>

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add additional information to the question, rather than in the comments.  Also does the API you are calling support XML payloads?